# Investment Mechanics

Tags: game-design, mechanics

I'm designing a board game about gem collecting. To collect gems players must invest on different gems in their turns (i.e. resource collecting is done using investment). Investment part in my design is as simple as follows:
There are 6 mines that can produce different gems, numbered 1 through 6. Each player chooses 3 gem mines then toss a d6 die. If the die number is equal to one of the chosen gem mines, then the player collects a gem.

This mechanic doesn't work too well for me, so I am looking for suggestions to improve it.
If you have a suggestion and you know that another game exists that uses a similar mechanic, please include that in your answer.

Comment: It's kind of unclear what you're asking here. How does throwing a die equate to investment in your game? What do you mean by investment mechanic? Just... anything where you spend resources now in order to get more later? So from Settlers you're basically calling the entire game an investment mechanic, building roads in order to build settlements in order to get more resources?

Comment: I edited your question to make it less broad. To do this, I had to focus on one aspect of your question: improving your own mechanic. If you're looking for information on other resource collection/investment mechanics, I would recommend you make a different question for this. Now let's see if we can get this re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the mechanic you came up with doesn't work well for 1 dice per player. Basically you're taking the luck of the dice roll, and adding another luck factor. You can cancel this out by allowing the use of more dice. What if the gems you collect can be used to purchase more dice?

You should take a look at the way resource collection is managed in [Stone Age](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_Age_%28board_game%29), as an inspiration.

Comment: Another idea: each player have 4 tokens, the player that is his/her turn must assign tokens to 6 mines (e.g. 2 tokens to mine#3, one token to mine#4 and one token to mine#6). After assignment the player toss 4 dice with 4 different colors(each color represent a gem type) and finally he/she collects N gem of color C if there is N token on mine number M and dice of color C is M! (e.g. if the player places 2 tokens on mine#3 and red dice is 3 then he/she collects 2 red gem)